# Common-mode gain of an instrumentation amplifier buffer stage

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, instrumentation-amplifier, common-mode

We discussed an instrumentation amplifier:

[image: Instrumentation Amplifier]

We were given the common-mode gain of the buffer pair (Op1 and Op2) for the common-mode output voltage \$\frac{1}{2}(U_{a+}+ U_{a-})\$ to be \$1+\frac{\Delta R_3}{2 R_4}\$ where \$ \Delta R_3 = R_3 - R‘_{3}\$.

But when I do the calculations (assuming ideal Op1 and Op2) I find:

$$U_{a+} + U_{a-} = (U_{in,+} + U_{in,-}) + \frac{\Delta R_3}{ R_4}(U_{in,+}-U_{in,-})$$

This can't evaluate to a constant gain in respect to the common mode \$\frac{1}{2}(U_{in,+}+ U_{in,-})\$. Furthermore, in the special case \$ U_{in,+} = U_{in,-} \implies I=0\$ said gain is 1, as the Ops just act as voltage followers.

All textbooks I found either assume \$ \Delta R_3 =0 \$ or neglect the second term by evaluating the special case.

How can one arrive at the proposed gain, and what am I doing wrong? Is my „definition“ of the common-mode gain wrong in this case, or is the solution to just ignore the voltages?

Comment: If R3 are unmatched, you get differential-to-common-mode conversion. Or in other words, you observe that CM gain appears to depend on the DM voltage. So IMO, a fixed CM gain cannot be defined, but you must define three gains: CM->CM gain (always 1, like you have observed), DM->CM gain, DM->DM gain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I do (assuming \$ U_{in}+ = U_{in-} = U_{in}\$)

$$
\frac{V_{a+}+V_{a-}}{2} = \frac{U_{in}\left(1+\frac{R_3}{R_4} - \frac{R_3 '}{R_4}\right) + U_{in}\left(1+\frac{R_3'}{R_4}  - \frac{R_3}{R_4}\right)}{2} = U_{in}
$$

You can easily see that the CM-to-CM gain equals 1. It doesn't matter whether there is mismatch in \$R_3\$ or not.
However, for the DM-to-CM gain, then, using the \$\frac{U_{in}}{2}\$ and \$-\frac{U_{in}}{2}\$, then you have:
$$
\frac{V_{a+}+V_{a-}}{2} = \frac{\frac{U_{in}}{2}\left(1+\frac{R_3}{R_4} - \frac{R_3 '}{R_4}\right) - \frac{U_{in}}{2}\left(1+\frac{R_3'}{R_4}  - \frac{R_3}{R_4}\right)}{2} = \frac{\frac{U_{in}}{2}\left(2\frac{\Delta R_3}{R_4}\right)}{2} = U_{in}\frac{\Delta R_3}{2R_4}
$$

The \$V_{a-}\$ in this case is the \$\frac{U_{in}}{2}\$ with the opposite polarity. You can see that if \$R_3\$ would be perfectly matched, then it DM-to-CM conversion gain would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the definitions of common & differential voltages are done in this way ...
\$ Vg1=Vcm + 1/2 * Vdiff. \$
\$ Vg2=Vcm - 1/2 * Vdiff. \$

[image]

Calculated voltages with "coefficients" for "Vcm" and "Vdiff" modes.
Calculated also Vo with limit when G -> infinity.

[image]

[image]

Note the added term Vdiff/Vcm for the "common_mode" gain.

And if one wants to see the "waveforms", here is the simulated circuit.

[image]

Added the waveforms for Common Mode for "viewing" "CM gain" (R2=10 kOhm and 20 kOhm).
It is always 1.

[image]

Comment: I guess you should add the plot `(v(Vo1)+v(Vo2))/2`, as that shows the intermediate CM signal. Further, one could plot that signal divided by `v(Vcm)`, which would show the instantaneous CM gain from the input to the intermediate stage. (The OP is not interested in the output signal, so the output difference amplifier could be removed for clarity)

Comment: Added transient. The division is not possible in transient waveforms (/0). CM gain always = 1.

Comment: Hmm, I see that your common mode intermediate signal is constantly equal to the common-mode input signal. However, this does not agree with my intuition and also not with Ernesto's analytical answer. I am wondering why 

Comment: @tobalt but if it's about the same, then it fits my answer because the CM-CM gain is 1, no?. The true suppression comes from the difference amplifier, I believe.

Comment: @ErnestoG Ah I get it now! In the last plot the red trace is with matched gain resistors - replicating the input common-mode signal. The green trace is with unmatched gain resistors (10k and 20k) showing that the "instantaneous common-mode gain" is different from 1 (because of the DM-to-CM conversion happening).

Comment: Hum ... The CM mode gain is always = 1 if one apply the "gain" calculated at the frequency of the CM signal which is at 1 kHz. The Diff signal at 50 Hz is then the "stranger" in this calculus ...

Comment: You are talking about the CM-to-CM gain (which is =1 and which produces a CM signal at the original frequency of the input CM signal). But you ignore that the DM-to-CM gain *also* contributes to the CM output signal as evidenced by your green trace. It creates a **CM output signal** at the DM input frequency.

Comment: Right ... My last formula with "Vdiff/Vcm".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below- we apply Vx/2 and -Vx/2 to the inputs so the net input CM voltage is zero. Now we need to find the resulting CM output voltage (Va + Vb)/2 as a function of the input *differential* voltage Vx.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2farMam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For ideal op-amps Vm = Vx/2 and Vn = -Vx/2.  So i1 = Vx/R4.

Va = Vx/2 + iR3

Vb = -Vx/2 - iR3'

(Va + Vb)/2 = i(R3-R3')/2  = \$\frac{Vx\cdot\Delta R3}{2\cdot R4}\$

So the output CM voltage gain for a differential input voltage is just:

Gcmdi = \$\frac{\Delta R3}{2\cdot R4}\$

It's easy to show that the output CM voltage gain for a common mode input voltage is 1, regardless of resistor imbalance.

I have a difficult time imagining any sensible definition of "common-mode gain" that allows us to **add** these two to get the stated equation though.